# uploading videos to server error

Tags: php, html

i need your help, im trying to upload video files to server, below are videoadmininsert.php, this file is what the user see, and videosave.php, is where the verification for the file are made , then save the file on a folder in the server.
the problem is when a choose a video file,for example the one i'm trying to upload got 25mb and the format is wmv, the server say that the file choosen was not the correct file extension.
videoadmin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="ccili_userccili"; // Mysql username
$password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Mysql password
$db_7name="ccili_BD"; // Database name
$tbl_name="Video"; // Table name


// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$_SESSION['whattodo']="insert";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title>Camara do comercio e industria Portugal - Iraque</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />

</head>
<body onload="display_ct(),display_ct2();">

<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
 <div id="Div1">
<div class="row dropdown-container fixed">
<div class="col-220">
<a id="logo" title="Back to amin" href="login_sucess.php">
<img width="220" alt="logo" src="../Images/logo.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-701 last">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="get-in-touch">
<img width="14" height="10" alt="" src="../Images/flagpt.jpg"/>
<strong>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display_c() {
    var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
    var strcount
    var x = new Date()
    var horas = x.getHours();
    var min = x.getMinutes();
    var sec = x.getSeconds();
    if (horas < 10) {
        horas = "0" + horas;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
        min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = horas + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " ";
    tt = display_c();
}

      </script> <span id='ct' ></span>
</strong>
<img width="14" height="10" alt="" src="../Images/flagiraque.jpg"/>
<strong>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_c2() {
    var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    mytime2 = setTimeout('display_ct2()', refresh)
}

function display_ct2() {
    var strcount
    var x = new Date()
    var horas1 = x.getHours() + 2;
    var min1 = x.getMinutes();
    var sec1 = x.getSeconds();

    if (horas1 < 10) {
        horas1 = "0" + horas1;
    }
    if (horas1 > 24) {
        horas1 = "0" + (horas1 - 24);
    }

    if (min1 < 10) {
        min1 = "0" + min1;
    }
    if (sec1 < 10) {
        sec1 = "0" + sec1;
    }
    document.getElementById('ct2').innerHTML = horas1 + ":" + min1 + ":" + sec1 + " ";
    tt1 = display_c2();
}



</script> <span id='ct2' ></span>
</strong>
</p>
<p class="text-right">غرفة التجارة و الصناعة البرتغالية العراقية</p>
<p class="text-right1">Câmara do Comércio e Indústria Portugal-Iraque</p>
<p class="text-right">ژووری بازرگانی عیراق پۆرتگال</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div class="hr">
<p class="text-rightLogout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out!!!</a></p>
 </div> 
<div class="row fixed">
<div class="col-220">
<ul id="news-box">
<FORM name="form1" method="post" action="checkbutton.php">
<p><b>Home</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button1" ID="Button1" VALUE="Edit Home."  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button2" ID="Button2" VALUE="Edit Culture PT" style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button3" ID="Button3" VALUE="Edit Culture IRAK" style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<b>About Us</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="Button4" ID="Button4" VALUE="Edit Mensagem Presidente"  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button5" ID="Button5" VALUE="Edit Administration Board"  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button6" ID="Button6" VALUE="Edit Consultive Board" style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button7" ID="Button7" VALUE="Edit General Assembly"  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button8" ID="Button8" VALUE="Edit Financial Council"  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name ="Button9" ID="Button9" VALUE="Edit Founding Members"  style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<b>Protocols</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button10"ID="Button10" VALUE="Edit Protocols"     style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<b>Links</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button11" ID="Button11" VALUE="Edit Links" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<b>Photos/News/Videos</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button12"ID="Button12" VALUE="Edit News" style="width:200px; height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button13"ID="Button13" VALUE="Edit Photos" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button14"ID="Button14" VALUE="Edit Videos" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<b>Associates</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button15"ID="Button15" VALUE="Edit How To Join" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button16"ID="Button16" VALUE="Edit List of Members" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button17"ID="Button17" VALUE="Edit Associates Prime" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
<b>Contacts</b>
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="Button18"ID="Button18" VALUE="Edit Adress" style="width:200px;height:30px;">
</FORM>
</p>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-460">
<?php
        echo "<center><h1>Videos</h1></Center>";
echo "<center><h1>Insert</h1></Center>";





 ?>

<form action="VideosAdminSave.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Insert Video</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Title</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="title" type="text" id="title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Text</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294">
<?php
echo "<input type='textarea' name='text1'  size='61'> </textarea>" ;

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>File</td>
<td><label for="file">Filename:</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submitVideos" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="40971520" type="hidden">

</table>
</td>
</form>



  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="row fixed">
<div class="col-220">
    <p >

        <img width="130" height="70"   alt="emb" src="Images/smartcom.jpg"/><br>
<strong>
&copy; 2012
<a href="http://www.smartcom.pt">Smartcom,
        <br/></a>Intelligent Communications&nbsp;


</strong>
</p>
<p >
All rights reserved.
<br/>

</p>
</div>
<div class="col-460 ">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

And here goes the videosadminsave

```
<?php

session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="ccili_userccili"; // Mysql username
$password='xxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Mysql password
$db_name="ccili_BD"; // Database name
$tbl_name="Video"; // Table name


// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_POST['Videos']))
{

 $delete=$_POST['Videos'];
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM Videos WHERE titulo='$delete' ");
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 

  window.location = ('VideosAdmin.php');
</script>";
  }
   $title=$_POST['title'];
//echo $namept;
$texto=$_POST['text'];

 $path="Videos/";

 $allowedExts = array("avi", "mp4", "flv","mpeg","3ggp","wmv");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/flv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/3ggp"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000000000000000000000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
 //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
 //alert("Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />");
 //</script>"; 
//echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Invalid File');window.location = ('VideosAdminInsert.php'); </script>";
  }
else
{
//echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
//echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
//echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
//echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

if (file_exists($path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {

  //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  //header("Location: editmsghome.php");
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('The file already exist, please change the file name.');window.location = ('VideosAdminInsert.php');
</script>"; 

  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  $path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        //header("Location: editmsghome.php");
//guardar na base de dados....
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//ob_start();
//session_start();
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
$video=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
else
{
$video="";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Video ( titulo,ficheiro) VALUES ('$title','$video')");


mysql_close($con);
//session_destroy();

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
  alert('The video was stored in the server '); 
  window.location = ('VideosAdmin.php');
 </script>";

  //fim de guardar na base de dados...

     }
  }

  }  
  else
  {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Didnt choose the correct file... ');window.location = ('VideosAdmin.php'); </script>";
    }




?>
```

Comment: It would help if the error message you say you receive actually exists in the code. What error do you receive exactly?

Comment: To jeroem  - the error message is didnt choose the correct message.

Answer (score 1):

Edited - after clarification from OP.

Your error handling says "in anything goes wrong, show the same message" which won't help you debug.

Most likely problem is the $_FILES is empty. You don't check for "isset($_FILES['file'])". To debug, simply print_r($_FILES); and see what you get. Some of the more critical file upload errors will result in $_FILES being empty, other errors will appear in $_FILES[name]['error'].

Also check the size - use a sensible limit as large number handling can get confusing (unless you cast as float, stick to integer numbers for valid comparisons, largest integer is either 2 billion or 9.3e16).

Your error checking should be:

1. isset($_FILES['file'])
2. $_FILES['file']['error']
3. is_uploaded_file   (just in case you're on a shared server)
4. Other criteria (name, size etc)

For each one, give a meaningful error message - this then helps breakdown exactly what the problem is.

Comment: the isset($_POST['Videos']), is for deleting videos,and ive got another page that handles that.

Comment: Argh - yep. Sorry, I didn't include that at first, but blamed $_FILES for being empty (which is now most likely culprit). But then reread, and it appeared the $_POST['videos'] was the problem. Helps if you layout the code nicely ;). Anyhow - the problem will most likely be $_FILES is empty, then. Answer amended accordingly. Debug by print_r($_FILES);